# How do I exclude match and change only specific character with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, find-and-replace

I am trying to use `sed` to replace '0' with the word 'correct' (I am using `echo $?` to validate my script and I want to replace the output of `echo`). The problem is that I have more text in the output file and `sed` is replacing everything and not just "0".

For example:

```
some command
echo ``date` `>> "file"
echo $? >> "file"
sed -i 's/0/correct/g' /"file"
```

Any ideas how could I get this working?

**EDIT 1 13.02.2014**

Output of `echo $?` is "0" (what I know is that 0 means everything is OK).

Next thing is that `sed -i 's/0/correct/g' /"file"` (I just used "" because somebody may misinterpret it with specific name).

Here is part of the script:

```
echo `date` | cat >> /file.txt
echo $? | cat >> /file.txt
sed -i 's/0/correct/g' /file.txt
```

`-i` means:

```
   text   Insert text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a back‐slash.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code snippet, the `sed` expression looks correct - it will replace every '0' character with the characters 'correct'. If you *only* want the output from your `echo` command to be updated, you could put the `sed` command on the output from `echo`, eg:

```
some command
date >> /file.txt
echo $? | sed 's/0/correct/' >> /file.txt
```

(note removing 'echo' and 'cat' commands will have no effect on the output)

In the context you're using the `-i` option, it's actually a commandline option, rather than a `sed` script command - it's a different section in the `man` page:

```
       -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

          edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```

This means it will update the source file (which is precisely what you want in your example).

However, note that in this example, the exit code being checked is the exit code of `date`, and not your command. In fact in your example, it's checking the exit code of `echo`, which I suspect is even less helpful for you.

A more standard way of performing this check would be along the lines of:

```
some command
result=$?
date >> /file.txt
if [ $result -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Command finished successfully" >> /file.txt
else
  echo "Command failed with exit code $result" >> /file.txt
fi
```

Comment: As your code suggests, every 0 was replaced with word correct.|
    Thu 13 Feb 2014 19:13:45 GMT > Thu 13 Feb 2correct14 19:13:45 GMT

Comment: What I want is to replace only 0 that was added with echo $? not the 0 in date and time. I want to set sed to replace only 0 and exclude 2014, 20:00 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace only the lines containing '0' and nothing else, use:

```
sed -i 's/^0$/correct/g' file.txt
```

Where `^` and `$` are special characters signalling the beginning and the end of the line respectively.

A potential issue could be if there are any other rows in the file only containing '0', not just the `$?` return values. A way to improve this would be to print more than just `$?`:

```
echo RETVAL: $?
```

And then later match this string:

```
sed -i 's/^RETVAL: 0$/correct/g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't need to search through the output file and make changes to it, then it would be easier to just change what you write to it in the first place.

With this bit of script, if the command is successful and returns an exit code of `"0"`, then  `"correct"` will be written to your file: `"/file.txt"`. If the command returns any other exit code, that exit code (number) will be written to your file.

```
some command
r=$?
[ $r -eq 0 ] && r="correct"
echo "`date` $r" >> /file.txt
```

Note: this will output the date, and your message ("correct") on the same line, which you may have wanted. If you wanted the date on one line, and your message on its own line, then change it to be two echo commands like:

```
some command
r=$?
[ $r -eq 0 ] && r="correct"
echo `date` >> /file.txt
echo $r >> /file.txt
```

There are (at least) two other possibilities you may be trying to accomplish:

First, if you ***only*** want to write to the file if the command is successful (returns an exit code of `"0"`). This will write `"correct"` to your file on success, but otherwise, if any other exit code is returned, then *nothing* will be written to your file:

```
some command
[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "`date` correct" >> /file.txt
```

Or, if you want to identify all exit codes where an exit code of `"0"` equals "correct", and any other exit code equals "error", then:

```
some command
r=$?
if [ $r -eq 0 ]; then
    r="correct"
else
    r="error: exit code $r"
fi
echo "`date` $r" >> /file.txt
```